# How to determine the static part of a regular expression at the beginning?

Tags: java, regex

Is there a safe way to determine that part of an regular expression that is static i.e. that matches only one string?

I have a regular expression for file paths and I want to extract that part at the beginning that doesn't require regular expression so that I can perform a direct search to speed up performance.

For example:

- `/some/path/.*\.jpg` => `/some/path/` and `.*\.jpg`
- `/files/[0-9a-f]{32}/.*` => `/files/` and `[0-9a-f]{32}/.*`
- `.*` => empty string and `.*`
- `/abc\.data/.*` => `/abc.data/` and `.*`

**EDIT**

The pattern could have any valid form. Maybe it doesn't even have a static part at the beginning but for the most times it does.

**EDIT 2**

My application is getting a file path and searches a pattern in the database that matches the file path. That table also contains the information about what should be done with the file. However, searching for the pattern takes a lot of time when I match with every string because I always have to scan the whole table. If I could extract that static part at the beginning I could limit the number of patterns I have to check.

Comment: Very hard with complex patterns AFAIK. Also have you tried to benchmark the current setup? Maybe you don't need to perform this new operation at all...

Comment: @HamZa Why is it harder with complex patterns if I only want the static part at the beginning?

Comment: @Bubletan It is static but I only need the static part at the beginning.

Comment: What about `(?:some/path/){1,1}.*\.jpg`? If your patterns are in the general form of `abc.*def`. Then you could simply split on `.*`

Comment: @JimmyT. Yeah, noticed and removed my comment.

Comment: Are you wanting to eliminate the part of the regex that is fixed, i.e. no metacharacters before you use it or eliminated the common prefixes after you use it?

Comment: Given the possibility of patterns like `abcd|efgh`, you'll need to do some digging to make sure the starting pattern is really static. Anyway, premature optimization is the root of all evil: Generally, don't try to optimize something unless you are sure it is giving you performance issues.

Comment: @dawg I want that part that is fixed.

Comment: @RealSkeptic What if I have performance issues?

Comment: Well, do you know for certain that they stem from searching with a regular expression rather than a static string? Can you put the information that pinpoints the regex as the bottleneck in your question in a way that the community will be able to reproduce?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Is my edit sufficient to explain why I'm getting the bottleneck?

Comment: @JimmyT. To provide a valid answer, we'd need to know what rules you followed when creating your patterns. Say, if all of the patterns start with a "static" part, then `.` or `[` (as I see from the current examples), then the answer is more or less evident.

Comment: @stribizhev I don't create the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing correctness of the input, you can split the string (regex) at the first occurence of char, that is "keyword" for regex. This way, you can get static part of regex, and then the real regex.

Comment: Which char do you mean?

Comment: Any not-escaped character that is "keyword for regex", like: `. [ ( *` and so.

Comment: If the expression is `a|b` then your solution won't work.